# Euler angles to directional vector

Tags: java, mathematics, vector

I wanted to implement a directional light system in my game, and instead of passing the direction to the light, I chose to use an angle, and only later convert it to a directional vector, so it is a bit more easier, to manage.

I tried to search on the internet for a good solution to this conversion, but the answers I found said different things (Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969798/plotting-a-point-on-the-edge-of-a-sphere#) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568568/how-to-convert-euler-angles-to-directional-vector)), and not always in understandable form (like using pitch, yaw and roll incorrectly). One of them said to use a format like

```
x = sin(roll) * sin(yaw)
y = sin(roll) * cos(yaw)
z = sin(yaw)
```

An other one used something like

```
x = cos(yaw) * cos(pitch)
y = cos(yaw) * sin(pitch)
z = sin(pitch)
```

So my question is:

What is the correct way to transform Euler angles (Tait-Bryan version) into a Directional vector?

Comment: There is no correct way to convert from Euler angles to a directional vector. It all depends on how you define your coordinate system relative to your angles. If I have the angles s and t, and let's give them both a value of zero. Which direction should I be facing now? Along the x-axis with the y-axis being up? Along the y-axis with the z-axis being up? Some other direction? This information is needed to be able to tell you what would be correct for your case. I also need to know around which axis will these angles be rotating around. And if they rotate clockwise you need to say that as well

Comment: Also consider renaming you angle variables to something other then x,y,z as those are typically used for values along their respective axis and the naming could lead to confusion. I recommend using s and t instead. Also if you do mention around what axis will these two angles represent.

Comment: x represents the angle around the x axis, y represents the angle around the y axis, etc. I change them to yar, pitch and roll

Comment: @Christer You should post this as an answer :)